# x label is outside of my figure because of figsize

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am constructing a simple graph with the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idl_t, idl_q = [[0, 20], [8, 24]], [[100, 100], [100, 100]]
dsc_t, dsc_q = [[8, 14], [12, 18]], [[100, 100], [5, 5]]
cha_t, cha_q = [[12, 18], [14, 20]], [[5, 5], [100, 100]]

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
plt.plot(idl_t, idl_q, color="blue", lw=2)
plt.plot(dsc_t, dsc_q, color="red", lw=2)
plt.plot(cha_t, cha_q, color="green", lw=2)
plt.xlabel("Time (hour)")
plt.show()
```

However, the code somehow cuts the x-label on figure as below:
[image: wrong graph]

I am pretty sure it is because of changing the `figsize` and seems that that it allocates label space proportionally to it. See the normal `figsize` figure below:
[image: right graph]

How can I preserve enough space for `xlabel` with different `figsize`s? And is it actually supposed to be like this as it seems as a bug for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`plt.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html)

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3))
plt.plot(idl_t, idl_q, color="blue", lw=2)
plt.plot(dsc_t, dsc_q, color="red", lw=2)
plt.plot(cha_t, cha_q, color="green", lw=2)
plt.xlabel("Time (hour)")
plt.tight_layout()  # <- HERE
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Update**

As suggested by [@TrentonMcKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney), you can also pass `tight_layout=True` as parameter of `plt.figure`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 3), tight_layout=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`constrained_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). It is more flexible than `tight_layout` (usually):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

idl_t, idl_q = [[0, 20], [8, 24]], [[100, 100], [100, 100]]
dsc_t, dsc_q = [[8, 14], [12, 18]], [[100, 100], [5, 5]]
cha_t, cha_q = [[12, 18], [14, 20]], [[5, 5], [100, 100]]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 3), constrained_layout=True)
ax.plot(idl_t, idl_q, color="blue", lw=2)
ax.plot(dsc_t, dsc_q, color="red", lw=2)
ax.plot(cha_t, cha_q, color="green", lw=2)
ax.set_xlabel("Time (hour)")
plt.show()
```

[image]